# How to can I programmatically edit a binary (x86)?

Tags: gcc, assembly, compiler-construction, x86, disassembly

I'm working on a program to do post-compilation optimization. Because I've noticed there are a few special cases that gcc just doesn't optimize well, even at -O3.

Is there a library that would allow me to load a binary (x86), into some datastructure that would be suitable for editing, and then write it out again? I would also want it to handle updating all the memory offsets, as the edits might change the size of the binary.

Comment: Disassemble, edit the disassembled code with any tools you like, and then assemble?

Comment: Can't you instead let gcc output the asm (option -S), edit that file, and compile the edited .s file? Or even better, patch gcc so that it does a better job? By the way, is there an entry in gcc's bugzilla about those missed optimizations?

Comment: See objdump and its code.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, yep, here's the one I'm currently trying to address: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56493

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose you are looking at ELF executable format. Say it if you were more thinking about PE or Mach-O.

You, indeed, can find several libraries or tools to edit an ELF format and modify it. Among others, here is a small list of such tools:

- [Elfesteem](http://hg.secdev.org/elfesteem/)
- [ERESI](http://www.eresi-project.org/)
- [PatchELF](http://nixos.org/patchelf.html)